# MySQL Workbench periodically errors on auto-save?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, mysql-workbench

What could cause this? It pops up every few minutes while MySQL Workbench is open.

I already tried the obvious, blunt-force fix, but it didn't work: Granting all permissions to Everyone in the entire AppData folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After renaming the connection to some more simple name e.g.: "MySite Live" the problem solved.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "simple" name?  Are you saying that particular characters or patterns are not allowed?  Your answer doesn't really provide enough information to be useful.